# Bluetooth device headset_audio_gateway profile change from available to not available during connection on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 4, with a Bluetooth USB Dongle. I'm trying to use the RPi as a headset connected in bluetooth to an Android device.

I followed this tutorial: https://scribles.net/hfp-on-raspberry-pi/ And get some informations from http://youness.net/raspberry-pi/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headset-or-speaker-to-raspberry-pi-3

I'm using:

kernel version 6.1.21
bluez version 5.55
Pulseaudio version 14.2
ofono version 1.31
The bluetooth connection is ok. I can set the device to use the headset_audio_profile and I can make a call.

After some time, not always the same, the bluetooth profile headset_audio_gateway became not available. The bluetooth connection is still ON, but this profile capabilities is "lost".

I need to disconnect/connect the device to get back the profile headset_audio_gateway available.

Any idea what could cause the behavior?

I tried with several android and iphone devices,n with same results: The headset_audio_gateway profile always stop to be available after a certain time.

Thank you